# Segmentation Fault from a While Loop C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to do a search from inside a map that would push all related children and later generations into a stack. `mined` is a json object declared before.

```
    if ( !mined[source].empty() ) {
        std::vector<std::string> minedDataVec = mined[source];
        while ( !minedDataVec.empty() ) {
            for (std::string s: minedDataVec) {
                stack.push(s);
                if ( !mined[s].empty() ) {
                    std::vector<std::string> minedDataVec = mined[s];
                } else {
                    minedDataVec.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault that I'm pretty sure has something to do with the while loop inside this code. Removing the while loop works but that would mean I'd have to manually add more code each time I want to search deeper within my map.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> minedDataVec = mined[s];` -- You are declaring a local variable here inside the `if` statement, and it has nothing to do with the `mindDataVec` you declared elsewhere.  Also, are you aware that a map's `operator []` will insert a blank entry if the entry doesn't exist?

Comment: You probably don't want to change the size of a container you're looping over in that loop. In your for loop, you cycle over each `s` in `minedDataVec`. Eventually, you might run `minedDataVec.clear()`, which will most likely cause the for each loop to increment an invalidated iterator or index into `minedDataVec` where it no longer exists. Additionally, when you write `std::vector<std::string> minedDataVec = mined[s];`, you are defining a variable that only exists in the scope of the if statement followed by never using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the vector named `minedDataVec` declared in the `if` block seems meaningless...

As for the Segmentation Fault, maybe it's because `minedDataVec.clear()` "*Invalidates any references, pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements.*" ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)).

The `range-for` loop `for (std::string s: minedDataVec)` has an implicit iterator to `minedDataVec`, which may become invalidated and cause a Segmentation Fault from an invalid read access.

Comment: How should I make the `minedDataVec` inside the `if` block meaningful? When I try `minedDataVec = mined[s];` I get an error saying `use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous`

Comment: Why you need to set `minedDataVec` again in the `if` block? Maybe you need another array to store all the element, using `vector.push_back`.